# Accessing admin model instance in form

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProductAdminForm()

class ProductAdminForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         super(ProductAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.fields['field1'] = forms.CharField(required=False)
         self.fields['field2'] = forms.IntegerField()
```

How can I pass product instance from ProductAdmin to ProductAdminForm? I want to provide different fields depending of products instances.

Answer (score 3):

this:

```
class ProductAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Product

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(ProductAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

             product_instance = self.instance
             if product_instance.id and product_instance.myField == "thatValue":
                 self.fields['field1'] = forms.CharField(required=False)
                 self.fields['field2'] = forms.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Ok, but I have a problem, I don't know what to substitute instead of ???? form = ProductAdminForm(instance=????)

Comment: you don't have to specify it. By default the instance is the Product currently edited (no instance if creation)

Comment: But Django throws KeyError exception for 'created' and 'instance'

Comment: Now I don't have this error, but self.instance.id, self.instance.price and others fields is None. I try to edit object, not to create, so it's strange that all is None.

Comment: Well, it works on my current project on edit. except I don't have the request parameter on my __init__, try remove it. and you must have `class Meta: model = Product` added on the ProductAdminForm definition as in my re-edited post.